# How to read the URL from a SharePoint list column of type hyperlink using JSOM?

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

One of the projects I am working on, I have a requirement to read the Hyperlink from a list called Asset List, please see below screenshot.

[image: Asset List]

AS you see I have four columns: Title, Stage (choice column with choices: Development, Transition and Property), Asset Link (hyperlink, clickable link), and Asset Description.

Basically this is a collaboration list where I am storing all subsites info and when clicked on the Asset link, it takes to the desired asset site.

For one of the coding solution, I have to read the URL portion of Asset Link when a stage value changes from Development to Property or from Transition to Property. How to do this using JSOM? Please help. Thanks.

FYI, I am working with SharePoint online/Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

Get hyperlink field value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var listItem = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("ListName").getItemById(1);
        context.load(listItem);
        context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            console.log(listItem.get_item("HyperLinkFieldName").get_description());
            console.log(listItem.get_item("HyperLinkFieldName").get_url());
        },
        function (sender, args) { alert(args.get_message()); }
        );
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. As per my question, I only want to read the URL if the Stage column value in the Asset List changes from either Development or Transition to Property, how do I make that working? Thanks again.

Comment: For this case, I think you need create a SharePoint add-in to monitor the item update event, refer this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/handle-list-item-events-in-the-provider-hosted-add-in